# Undefined variable for type_file, name_file, size_file and tmp_file

Tags: php, forms, image, file

I would like to get the name and the type of the image sent in my form and send them in database but when I do a var_dump($name_file, $type_file, $size_file, $tmp_file);

I have this messages :

> Notice: Undefined variable: type_file in C:\wamp64\www\sg-actus\pages\admin-articles.php on line 117
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: name_file in C:\wamp64\www\sg-actus\pages\admin-articles.php on line 117
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: size_file in C:\wamp64\www\sg-actus\pages\admin-articles.php on line 117
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: tmp_file in C:\wamp64\www\sg-actus\pages\admin-articles.php on line 117

The line 117 corresponds to the line of my var_dump.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES['file']) && !empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['publier']) )
{
    $content_dir = '../assets/images/articles/';

    $tmp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $type_file = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $size_file = $_FILES['file']['size'] / 1000;
    $name_file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    if (empty($_POST['descriptionArticle']))
    {
        echo "Description non renseignée";
    }
    elseif(strlen($_POST['descriptionArticle']) > 255)
    {
        echo "Description trop longue";
    }
    elseif( !is_uploaded_file($tmp_file) )
    {
        exit("Veuillez choisir un fichier");
    }
    elseif( !strstr($type_file, 'jpg') && !strstr($type_file, 'jpeg') && !strstr($type_file, 'bmp') && !strstr($type_file, 'gif') && !strstr($type_file, 'png'))
    {
        exit("Le fichier n'est pas une image");
    }
    elseif ($size_file > 5000000 )
    {
        exit("Le fichier est trop volumineux ( > 5Mo )");
    }
    elseif( !move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $content_dir . $name_file) )
    {
        exit("Impossible de copier le fichier dans".$content_dir);
    }
    elseif( preg_match('#[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F/\\\\]#', $name_file) )
    {
        exit("Nom de fichier non valide");
    }
    else 
    {
        while ( file_exists($content_dir . $name_file) )
        {
            $name_file = rand(0, 99) . $name_file;
        }
        // Insertion dans la bdd
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO article(article_titre, article_description, auteur, article_image, article_image_type, article_contenu, categorie, article_date) 
                              VALUES(:titre, :description, :auteur, :image, :type_file, :contenu, :categ, NOW())');
        $req->execute(array('titre' => $_POST['titreArticle'],
                            'description' => $_POST['descriptionArticle'],
                            'auteur' => $_POST['auteur'],
                            'image' => $name_file,
                            'type_file' => $type_file,
                            'contenu' => $_POST['contenuArticle'],
                            'categ'=>$_POST['categorie']));

        echo "L'article a bien été publié";
    }
}
?>
<form action="admin-articles" method="post">

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label for="categorieArticle">Catégorie</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="categorieArticle">
                        <?php 
                            $categ = array();
                            $categ = get_categories();
                            foreach ($categ as $value) { echo "<option value='" . $value['id_categorie'] . "'>" . $value['nom_categorie'] . "</option>" ; } 
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label for="auteurArticle">Auteur</label>
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" readonly name="auteurArticle" id="auteurArticle" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['auteur']['id_auteur'] ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['auteur']['nom_auteur'] ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['auteur']['nom_auteur'] ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label for="titreArticle">Titre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" name="titreArticle" id="titreArticle" placeholder="Titre de l'article">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label for="descriptionArticle">Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" style="width:100%;" name="descriptionArticle" id="descriptionArticle" placeholder="Description de l'article (255 caractères max)"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file">Image de l'article</label>
                    <input type="file" id="inputFile" name="file">
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label for="contenuArticle">Contenu de l'article</label>
                    <textarea id="contenuArticle" name="contenuArticle" placeholder="Contenu de l'article"></textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" name="publier" class="btn btn-default">Envoyer</button>

                <?php var_dump($name_file, $type_file, $size_file, $tmp_file);

                ?>

        </form>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: When your format isn't submitted your variables dont exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Show  your html form tag attributes
May be you missing enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

Comment: Your weIcome, i  am glad @ElGecko

Comment: Because you move image in folder with as it is name but when you insert image name in database you add random number with its name 'rand(0,99) so keep both name same

Comment: yes it's solved, thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome @Elgecko